# php session on refresh page or on button submit

Tags: php

My site url like this: http://localhost/record/index.php
when I add,update,delete record from table then my url like this: http://localhost/record/index.php?delmsg=Users%20has%20been%20deleted
how Can I remove this php variable on refresh page or button submit using session

Comment: show us some code

Comment: store `delmsg` variable in session to show messages. Not in url.

Comment: $delmsg=$_GET['delmsg'];
echo "<h2 align='center' style='color: saddlebrown;'>" . $delmsg . "</h2>";

Comment: header('Location: index.php?delmsg=User ID = ' . $del_id . ' has been deleted');

Comment: @ArslanKiyani please add whole redirect code which calling for events in question.

Comment: if you show us proper code then we can easily understand it and guide you to proper solution

Comment: @shyammakwana.me how to delmsg store in session please write it some code here or give me a useful link

Comment: if (isset($_GET['del'])){
 $del_id = $_GET['del'];
 
if (mysqli_query($sql,"Delete from user where id = '$del_id'")){
 header('Location: index.php?delmsg=User ID = ' . $del_id . ' has been deleted');
 
 }

Comment: This is mine del.php page

Comment: Don't post your code in comment box. Edit your post for updates.

Comment: <?php

error_reporting(0);
$msg=$_GET['message'];
echo "<h2 align='center' style='color: saddlebrown;'>" . $msg . "</h2>";

$editmsg=$_GET['editmsg'];
echo "<h2 align='center' style='color: saddlebrown;'>" . $editmsg . "</h2>";

$delmsg=$_GET['delmsg'];
echo "<h2 align='center' style='color: saddlebrown;'>" . $delmsg . "</h2>";

?>

Comment: @ArslanKiyani here is all you need : http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: this code is add on index.php page

Comment: Learn some PHP basics and `how to code` tutorials, then post questions here if you're stuck.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are right trying to remove this message handling from the GET variables, using sessions is a lot better and let GET control the logic is not safe as some users pointed.

Use `session_start();` in the beginning of every PHP file where you want to handle the session values.

To set a value that you want to read later:

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $del_id = intval($_GET['del']); // intval will improve security
    if (mysqli_query($sql,"Delete from user where id = ".$del_id.";")) {
        $_SESSION["delmsg"] = "User ID = " . $del_id . " has been deleted";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

To read the value in a further request and show contents accordingly:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["delmsg"])) {
    echo "<div class='message'>".$_SESSION["delmsg"]."</div>";
    // clean up the session variable value if you don't need it anymore
    unset($_SESSION["result"]);
}
```

This code will help you understand session variables, but there are still security flaws in this code, don't go live with it. First, learn about SQL Injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Hope it helps.

---

Read more about the `$_SESSION` array: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score -1):

after successful add, update or delete record redirect your page back to the same page using a `header` like below.

```
header('location:yourpage.php');
exit;
```